# How to overwrite global variables in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, global-variables

I am trying to execute a jmx file in such a way if the Report_Status goes to false it should overwrite initially declared global variable value as well
heres my code

```
var Status = WDS.vars.get("ReportStatus");
WDS.log.info("Original ReportStatus: " + Status);
Status = "fail";
WDS.vars.put("ReportStatus", Status);
WDS.log.info("Updated ReportStatus: " + 
WDS.vars.get("ReportStatus"));
```

it is updating in log.info but it is not overwritng in user defied variables below

[Please view image for clear understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlnZw.png)

Answer (score 0):

It will not "overwrite" the "global" variable.

As per [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) documentation:

> The User Defined Variables element lets you define **an initial set of variables**, just as in the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan).

and

> Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - are processed at the start.

As per [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) documentation:

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

So your "requirement" doesn't make sense because even if you manage to update the value (and it will be tricky because the property is read-only) it won't have any impact because it's processed when the test plan is initialized, further changes won't be taken into consideration.

If you're looking for a **global** flag which will act as a pass/fail criteria for the whole test you can consider using a JMeter Property instead like instead of

```
WDS.vars.put("ReportStatus", Status);
```

do

```
WDS.props.put("ReportStatus", Status);
```

and then refer to the status `${__P(ReportStatus,)}` where required

More information: [Using User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables)